# Use existing models with FactoryGirl associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, factory-bot, factory

I have some models setup with FactoryGirl and I want to do associations between them. The association keyword on the particular models is super helpful! However, I don't want to create new models which I think is what the association keyword does. I want to associate with already created instances of my particular model, or have the option to do so easily. I know there is a code smell in here somewhere with all this setup, but an example is below.

```
obj1 = create(:thing_one)
obj2 = create(:thing_two, :with_thing_one)
```

would be the setup I'm doing right now (but with a few more models and associations than just two) and it doesn't have the obj2 and obj1 objects associate properly in the database. If I do something like

```
obj1 = create(:thing_one)
obj2 = create(:thing_two, thing_one: obj1)
```

It would associate everything correctly.

The problem is that this makes it seem like it would be more work than it's really worth to use the Factories if I just have to setup everything myself. Why wouldn't I just use ActiveRecord and manually setup those objects?

EDIT:

Another situation that could come up is the following:

```
obj1 = create(:object)
obj2 = create(:object_two, needed_object: obj1)
# obj3 is dependent on obj2 being created which is dependent on obj1
obj3 = create(:object_three, needed_object_two: obj2)
```

Answer (score 0):

FactoryGirl includes [associations](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#rails-preloaders-and-rspec) you can very easily use existing factories. The example below assumes you have orders that belong_to a customer.

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :order do
    association :customer, factory: :customer
  end
end
```

Comment: right, sorry i guess i needed to clarify a bit. i edited the question but the main problem i keep seeing is that i need the particular model for whatever association for multiple different factories and that dependency is causing issues for me. lemme know if that makes sense, appreciate the answer!